# Ignore "other" domains when downloading with wget?

Tags: command-line, wget

I would like to crawl links under www.website.com/XYZ and only download the links that is under www.website.com/ABC.

I am using the following wget command to get the files I want:

```
wget  -I ABC -r -e robots=off --wait 0.25  http://www.website.com/XYZ
```

This works perfectly when I use wget 1.13.4. But the problem is I have to use this command on a server which has wget 1.11 and when I use the same command, it ends up downloading additional domains such as:

```
www.website.de 
www.website.it 
...
```

How can I avoid this problem? I tried using

```
--exclude domains=www.website.de,www.website.it
```

however it kept downloading those domains.

Also note that I can't use `--no-parent` since the files I want is in upper level (I want files under website.com/ABC by crawling links under website.com/XYZ).

Any hints?

Comment: Don't use "fake" URLs, and don't use the URL of a site that has nothing to do with your problem. The domains you listed are in no way "subdomains", they are just different domains, probably belonging to the same company.

Comment: Something is wrong here.  `wget` should not cross hosts by default, and you need the `-H`/`--span-hosts` option to cross hosts when doing a recursive wget.  "www.website.com" is a completely different host from "www.website.de".

Comment: @guntbert  sorry, i thought giving the real url would be a problem. of course, the website I want to crawl is not website.com. but when I crawl example.com, I also see example.it, example.de in the main directory (the same level with example.com).

Comment: @jw013 like i said above, when i just give www.example.com/x it also crawls www.example.de, www.example.it. BUT this only happens with wget 1.11 not 1.13.. So that's why I am very confused.

Comment: This looks like a bug: wget 1.11 shouldn't behave differently, `-H` has always been required to recurse outside the original host. Does `-D www.website.com` help?

Comment: @Gilles Nope, unfortunately it doesn't work. Can it be the case that wget was configured to use -H by default? If so, is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/wgetrc` or `~/.wgetrc`? But even with `-H`, passing `-D` should have limited wget to that one host.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
--exclude domains=www.website.de,www.website.it
```

The right way is:

```
--exclude-domains www.website.de,www.website.it
```

From the wget man page:

> ```
> --exclude-domains domain-list
>       Specify the domains that are not to be followed.
> ```

Comment: mustn't the  list be komma separated?

Comment: @rubo77 You're right, I've changed that.

Answer (score 27):

You may try `--max-redirect 0` or use `--domains example.com`
 as opposite of `--exclude-domains example.com`.

See:

```
  -D,  --domains=LIST              comma-separated list of accepted domains.
       --exclude-domains=LIST      comma-separated list of rejected domains.
       --follow-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of followed HTML tags.
       --ignore-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of ignored HTML tags.
  -np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
  --max-redirect                   maximum redirections allowed per page.
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer if you like white-listing the domains instead of black listing